# Fragments, GWT.runAsync and AsyncProvider

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, fragment

My *understanding* is that `GWT.runAsync` is called any time you wish to implement "codesplitting" and trigger a new exclusive fragment to download.

My *understanding* is that it is recommended (by GWT) to design/develop functionality for a particular fragment in such a way that it can be downloaded once into a singleton instance of `AsyncProvider` and reused again and again.

My questions are:

1. If I'm using an MVP pattern, does this "`AsyncProvider`" style apply to models, views and presenters? In other words, do I have to code in such a way that Model/View/Presenter "MVP-1" doesn't reference code inside of Models/Views/Presenters "MVP-2", so that when an `AsyncProvider` calls `GWT.runAsync` and pulls down the fragment for MVP-1, its a nice, clean, dependency-free download? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the `AsyncProvider` pattern altogether?
2. What is an `AsyncProxy` and how does it fit in here?
3. Why would a fragment need to be reused again and again? In other words, what's the benefit of the `AsyncProvider` pattern to begin with?!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Splitting and MVP are 2 differents things, it means that you don't need MVP for code splitting, but it's a very good thing to do with MVP.

Broadly speaking, a UI with GWT, it's lot of components (View/Presenter) put together, each component can be code with MVP or not. And when a component call an other component, you must use `GWT.runAsync`, if you want to split your code.
So for the first question: yes, `AsyncProvider` works with MVP.

For the others questions, I invite you to watch the [Google I/O 2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y) at 32:55, it's explained well.

Personaly I use and recommend Code Splitting with Places & Activities, see [issue 5129](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5129)

Comment: Thanks @BoomBoom49 (+1) - a quick followup: let's use that speaker's example where we have a tabbed panel (with multiple tabs), and we only want to fetch the code for a particular tab's view when the user actually clicks on the tab and wants to see it (instead of being hid behind all the other tabs). The code to required to display this view - which we would need to codeplit and download via `GWT.runAsync()`, might consist of `Tab4Presenter`, `Tab4View`, `Tab4StartButton`, `Tab4PieChart`, etc ("Tab4" is the tab we're talking about). Can you please provide a quick code sample that shows how...

Comment: ...the `AsyncProvider` and/or `AsynchProxy` pattern can specifically fetch this "fragment" of code (just the `Tab4<x>` components)? I think seeing this in action will help me connect all the dots here. Thanks again!

Comment: If you use a TabPanel, it would be difficult to do, but nut impossible.

Comment: ... I recommend to use standard button instead.
It depends a lot of your code organization.
But if you have a navigation zone like your tab, and a content zone, when the user click on a tab, your start `GWT.runAsync()` and in the call you send a event and this event is caught by the content zone which will show the right interface.

Comment: when I say standard button, it works but a Label is more appropriate